# Handling several instances and states of the same entity

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
s = Session()
s.autoflush = False
s.autocommit = False

p1 = s.query(Person).first()
print p1 #prints 'Ivan Petrov', correct name of a person #1
p1.name = 'John Smith' #change the person's name

p2 = s.query(Person).first()
print p2 #prints 'John Smith', but the object wasn't flushed yet.
```

So, the question is - how do I correctly handle this situation? I need changes to p1 NOT to affect the session (and p2) until I say so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to detach the object from the session:

```
session.expunge(p1)
```

To reattach you could try:

```
p2 = session.merge(p1)
```

Or use different session object. But sooner or later the fact that you manipulate the same entity will come up.

Comment: But then I can't just reattach it back, because p2 references the same persistant entity: "sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Can't attach instance <Person at 0x3cb4550>; another instance with key (<class 'models.Person'>, (1,)) is already present in this session."

Answer (score 1):

A good deal of work was put in SQLALchemy for it to work the way it does right - and not teh way you are needing it now.

One way I can think of doing this, without knowing much of SQLAlchemy internals, is to create a proxy object with the instance you are changing, and have all changes there to change the original object only when told to.

```
class AlchemyProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, obj):
        self._obj = obj
        self._changes = []

    def __setattr__(self, attr, value):
        self._changes.append((attr, value)
        # change the attributes in this instance
        return object.__setattr__(self, attr, value)

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        # This is only called when the requested attribute was not
        return getattr(self._obj, attr)

    def _commit(self):
        for attr, value in self._changes:
            setattr(self._obj, attr, value)
```

And use it like:

```
p1 = AlchemyProxy(s.query(Person).first())
```

Comment: Frankly, I hope to retain an ability to work with my domain model objects directly - calling their methods, etc - without adding wrappers and layers if that is possible.